# Exclude last occurrence on line from Regex match

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, notepad++

I would like to select all whitespaces except the last occurrence on each line so that I can replace the whitespaces with a single delimiter for import purposes.

[image]

The matches are all groups of whitespaces. There are CRLF at the end of each line. I tried with and without $, \r\n etc.. I feel like I am missing soemthing very obvious but wasnt able to pin it down with google so far.

I tried negative lookahead already. Unfortunately in Notepad++ the *CRLF is included* in the match, so that when I try to replace the data it strips away the new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well what you are trying to do,

with regexpal (check the m modifier box):

```
(?=([^\r\n\S]+))\1(?!$)
```

where `(?=(...))\1` is a trick to emulate an [atomic group](http://regular-expressions.mobi/atomic.html) with javascript and `[^\r\n\S]` is like `\s` but without `\r` and `\n`

with notepad++:

```
\h++(?!$)
```

where `\h` stands for any horizontal whitespace (this class is not available in javascript too) and ++ is a [possessive quantifier](http://regular-expressions.mobi/possessive.html). Note that by default `$` means the end of the line in notepad++.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Why is the syntax so different between the two apps?

Comment: @KarmaEDV: because atomic grouping, possessive quantifiers and the class `\h` are not available with javascript regex used by regexpal, notepad++ uses the boost implementation of PCRE.